# Is it possible to make the devtool status off when using Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

is it possible to make the devtool status off when using Puppeteer?
because there are some websites that protect their pages from being inspected using devtool, so it can not be accessed using Puppeteer.

I opened this url https://jsbin.com/cecuzeb/edit?js,output to check devtool status

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  devtools: false,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://jsbin.com/cecuzeb/edit?js,output');
```

is there any way to make this status off?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is rather a theoretical version to prevent detection by normal dev tools detection using `/./.toString` method based on the provided jsbin link on main question.

- Stop all intervals of page. Since most devtool detection libraries are simply running the interval check, we can stop them.

  ```
  (function(w){w = w || window; var i = w.setInterval(function(){},100000); while(i>=0) { w.clearInterval(i--); }})(/*window*/);
  ```
- Stop `console.clear`, if there are no `console.clear` running, then you won't have problem with the console getting cleared without your permission. Also stop printing "%c" or any other clearing characters.

  ```
  console.clear = console.log = console.warn = console.error = () => {};
  ```